# Maximize $x^\intercal\,A\,x$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be a symmetric matrix. I'm trying to find the $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ with $\lVert x \rVert = 1$ so that $x^\intercal\,A\,x$ is maximized. Intuitively, I'd say that this is the case if $x$ is the normalized eigenvector corresponding to the largest eigenvalue of $A$.

Is this correct? If so, how would I prove it?

EDIT: What about the following:
$x^\intercal\,A\,x = x^\intercal\,(\frac12 A + \frac12 A) x = \frac12x^\intercal\,A + \frac12\,A\,x = \frac12\,A\,x + \frac12\,A\,x = A\,x$

Then the claim is obvious knowing that $A$ has real eigenvalues?

Comment: In your edit you have not used the distributive law correctly.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip You're right, thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct. Use the following hint to prove it.

Hint: Use the eigenvalue decomposition of $A=U^T\Lambda U$ and define $y=Ux$, so that $||y||=||x||=1$

Comment: Could you expand on this slightly?

Comment: Using the decomposition you can write $x^{T}Ax$ as $y^T\Lambda y$. You can then write it as the weighted sum of eigenvalues of $A$. Just write this down and then show that this sum is upper bounded by the maximum eigenvalue.

Answer (score 0):

You are indeed correct that the maximized value of $x^\intercal\,A\,x$ would be the largest eigenvalue of A and the normalized eigenvector that corresponds to it.

Have you studied quadratic forms? And how diagonal matrices will relate to them?